# Horizontal and vertical alignment of an element to the centre of a whole page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, vertical-alignment

I am trying to place a code frame generated with `listings` package in the middle of a page both horizontal and vertical. How can I do it?

Edit I:

```
My code is this:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,title=1.1]

Code goes here!

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this code frame part of a floating environment? If so, and assuming you're using a standard document class, using the `[p]` placement specifier should achieve the vertical centering job. Separately, `\centering` should get the horizontal centering job done.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly that means but I edited my question and I added a simplified version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\vfill
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,title=1.1]

Code goes here!

\end{lstlisting}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked! Can you please explain me what exactly happened?

Comment: @Adam  Well, `\vfill` is vertical glue.  Think rubberband, stretched between what's above it and what's below it.  In this case, there is noting above and below, and so the free ends of the glue are attached to the top/bottom margins.  The item is stretched halfway in between (try 2 `\vfills` above and 1 below to get 2/3, 1/3 breakdown).  The `\leavevmode` gets you out of "vertical mode", which was needed in this case, to allow the top `\vfill` to work.